# session_id() is not entering in to DB?

Tags: php, session

I am able to `echo session_id()` and all that. But I can't seem to enter the `session_id()` to the Table.

Here is my function:

```
public function login($email, $password) {
    $row = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('email', '=', $email));

    $password = $row->first()->user_salt . $password;
    $password = $this->hashData($password);

    $is_active = (boolean) $row->first()->is_active;
    $is_verified = (boolean) $row->first()->is_verified;

    if ($email == $row->first()->email && $password == $row->first()->password) {
        $match = true;
    } else {
        $match = false;
    }

    if ($match == true) {
        if ($is_active == true) {
            if ($is_verified == true) {
                $random = $this->randomString();
                $token = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $random;
                $token = $this->hashData($token);

                $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row->first()->id;
                $userid = $row->first()->id;
                $session = session_id();
                echo $session;

                $deleteold = DB::getInstance()->delete('active_users', array('user_id', '=', $userid));

                $insertnew = DB::getInstance()->insert('active_users', array(
                                'user_id'       => $userid,
                                'session_id'    => $session,
                                'token'         => $token
                            )); 

                if ($insertnew != false) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 3;
            } else {
                // NOT VERIFIED
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            // NOT ACTIVE
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have declared the `$session = session_id();` and my echo displays the id with no problem, but when I insert into the DB, the only value stored is 0. Why I can't store the `session_id()`?

Comment: What is the type of session_id in your database schema?

Comment: Sounds like you're defining session_id as an INT in the DB. You might want to check the docs to see what `session_id()` actually returns: https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php.

Comment: write session_start(); at the top of your page

Comment: How does your table look like?

Comment: @this.lau_ OMG i cant believe after all this time i missed that. I had it set to INT instead of VarChar, Thanks mate that was great. I should have known that haha silly me. Can you write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_id()` returns a string, but it seems it's being saved as an integer in your database. If you change the type of session_id to varchar in your db schema, it should work.